# Spark Java DataFrame sum and drop duplicate based on columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataFrame as below:

**INPUT**

```
+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------+
| accountId|accountNumber|acctNumberTypeCode|cisDivision|currencyCode|priceItemCd|priceItemParam|priceItemParamCode|processingDate|txnAmt|  txnDttm|txnVol|udfChar1|  udfChar2|  udfChar3|
+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------+
|2032000000|   2032000000|          C1_F_ANO|         CA|         USD| PRICEITEM2|            UK|           Country|    2018-06-06|   100|28-MAY-18|   100|   TYPE1|PRICEITEM1|PRICEITEM2|
|2032000000|   2032000000|          C1_F_ANO|         CA|         USD| PRICEITEM2|            UK|           Country|    2018-06-06|   100|28-MAY-18|   100|   TYPE1|PRICEITEM1|PRICEITEM2|
|1322000000|   1322000000|          C1_F_ANO|         CA|         USD| PRICEITEM1|            US|           Country|    2018-06-06|   100|28-MAY-18|   100|   TYPE1|PRICEITEM1|PRICEITEM2|
|1322000000|   1322000000|          C1_F_ANO|         CA|         USD| PRICEITEM1|            US|           Country|    2018-06-06|   100|28-MAY-18|   100|   TYPE1|PRICEITEM1|PRICEITEM2|
```

Now I want to perform,

1. Sum of "txnAmt" column for the records having same accountId and account numbers.
2. Drop duplicate records.

**Output**

```
+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------+
| accountId|accountNumber|acctNumberTypeCode|cisDivision|currencyCode|priceItemCd|priceItemParam|priceItemParamCode|processingDate|txnAmt|  txnDttm|txnVol|udfChar1|  udfChar2|  udfChar3|
+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------+
|2032000000|   2032000000|          C1_F_ANO|         CA|         USD| PRICEITEM2|            UK|           Country|    2018-06-06|   200|28-MAY-18|   100|   TYPE1|PRICEITEM1|PRICEITEM2|
|1322000000|   1322000000|          C1_F_ANO|         CA|         USD| PRICEITEM1|            US|           Country|    2018-06-06|   200|28-MAY-18|   100|   TYPE1|PRICEITEM1|PRICEITEM2|
```

I am not sure how to perform step 1?

I have written code to perform step 2, drop the duplicates based on accountId and account numbers:

```
String[] colNames = {"accountId", "accountNumber"};
Dataset<RuleOutputParams> finalDs = rulesParamDS.dropDuplicates(colNames);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can two rows have the same `accountId` and `accountNumber` but different values in other columns?

Comment: You're not dropping duplicates... You are aggregating them

Comment: @Shaido yes it is possible.

Comment: So when you do the aggregation (or dropping), if for example the `txnDttm` has different values while `accountId` and `accountNumber` are the same. How do you know which value of `txnDttm` to keep? Both?

Comment: @cricket_007 finalDS has only unique rows based on values of accountId and account number, I thought it has dropped remaining rows, can you please point something out which can lead me to complete the requirement.

Comment: You're "combining" matching rows on the first two columns. Nothing is being "dropped". In SQL terms, you are doing a `SUM` over a window/group

Comment: @Shaido it is an assumption here that txnDttm will have same values for all the rows. because the transactions are for same day.

Comment: @cricket_007 okay but when I am taking count number of records are reduced. so dropDuplicates method doesn't drop the duplicate rows is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load data and make a SQL table for it

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).load("data.csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("t")
```

Then, what you need are called [Window Aggregation functions](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-functions-windows.html), plus a trick with `row_number()` to remove the duplicates

```
val df2 = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    sum(txnAmt) OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, accountNumber) s, 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, accountNumber ORDER BY processingDate) r FROM t) 
  WHERE r=1""")
  .drop("txnAmt", "r")
  .withColumnRenamed("s", "txnAmt")
```

And if you show that, you'll see

```
+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------+------+
| accountId|accountNumber|acctNumberTypeCode|cisDivision|currencyCode|priceItemCd|priceItemParam|priceItemParamCode|processingDate|  txnDttm|txnVol|udfChar1|  udfChar2|  udfChar3|txnAmt|
+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------+------+
|2032000000|   2032000000|          C1_F_ANO|         CA|         USD| PRICEITEM2|            UK|           Country|    2018-06-06|28-MAY-18|   100|   TYPE1|PRICEITEM1|PRICEITEM2| 200.0|
|1322000000|   1322000000|          C1_F_ANO|         CA|         USD| PRICEITEM1|            US|           Country|    2018-06-06|28-MAY-18|   100|   TYPE1|PRICEITEM1|PRICEITEM2| 200.0|
+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+----------+----------+------+
```

---

As a side note, one might try to add more columns to the following, but you would need to add them to the group by clause

```
spark.sql("SELECT accountId, accountNumber, SUM(txnAmt) txnAmt FROM t GROUP BY accountId, accountNumber").show
+----------+-------------+------+
| accountId|accountNumber|txnAmt|
+----------+-------------+------+
|2032000000|   2032000000| 200.0|
|1322000000|   1322000000| 200.0|
+----------+-------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation however when I have written val df2 = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    sum(txnAmt) OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, accountNumber) s, 
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, accountNumber ORDER BY processingDate) r FROM t) 
  WHERE r=1""")
  .drop("txnAmt", "r")
  .withColumnRenamed("s", "txnAmt") query it is giving compiler error

Comment: Java doesn't use triple quotes like Scala does. Or `val` keyword

Comment: yes I tried  with single quotes and compiler error was resolved. Thanks.

Comment: When I am writing the final DF in csv file instead of creating one csv file , it creates different csv files for different rows(records) , why is so?

Comment: Spark is distributed over many CPUs and computers. When you do `write("file.csv")`, it makes a **directory**. One file per Spark partition. https://forums.databricks.com/questions/2848/how-do-i-create-a-single-csv-file-from-multiple-pa.html

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.